# why i can't change a variable in an if statement with swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, if-statement, swift

I have a short question. Why can't I change the value of the var Test in a if statement?

```
if Status == 1{
    var Test = 1
}
else{
    var Test = 2
}

println(Test) // Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'Test'
```

Comment: we should use hump naming in Swift.Example: variable name -  test; class/struct name - Test.

Answer (score 7):

because `Test` is out of your scope. `Test` is defined in two different `if(){}` scopes.
Declaring `Test` outside of the `if()` scope will allow you to access it in a broader scope.

```
var Test :Int

if Status == 1{
    Test = 1
}
else{
    Test = 2
}

println(Test)
```

EDIT: A undeclared variable (Test) cannot be inferred from, therefore recommend to specify variable type (:=Int for integer). If there is any other type of value, an error will be displayed.